# How to access Laravel native log files(storage/logs/) from AWS ECS container?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I have containerized a Laravel application on AWS ECS service. I am unable to access the native log files i.e. from 'storage/logs'. I am able to stream each container's logs to CloudWatch service but not able to do the same for these native logs.

Comment: Could you setup a cron to upload these logs to s3?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747744/5372316

Comment: @shelly It worked. Thanks a lot.